# Laravel 5.1 Net_SFTP has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, phpseclib, laravelcollective

I'm using `Laravel 5.1` with the package [`laravelcollective/remote`](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote) to run an SSH command on a remote server:

```
\SSH::into('myserver')->run($commands);
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Net_SFTP has a deprecated constructor

I can see that the error is coming from [`phpseclib`](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) package, and on newer versions they have fixed that. (They changed the function name to `__construct`), but I can't update `phpseclib` package because I don't include it on my `composer.json` file, `laravelcollective/remote` does this.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Write a pull request? May the power of open source be with you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot and should not solve this as it has already been fixed as you correctly stated.

The warnning about the deprecated construtor method is only a warning/info. This does not influence your application. As soon as *laravellcollective* include the newer version of `phpseclib` in their composer.json this warning will disappear. Of course you need the check from time to time and update your application with a `composer update`.